# Multithreaded mysql Connection Pooling for Java Application

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling

.I have developed a java Application that downloads html from specified urls.I am able to download in multithreads .But now i want to use connection Pooling as well.I searched for various ways we can perform connection pooling but all are related to client server applications (using apache, Tomcat etc). But I need this on my single machine only.Here i just want to download html and insert into Mysql database in threads. How can I do that.

Comment: Static (singleton) BoneCP instance. http://jolbox.com/ Or write your own! Static synchronized collection with synchronized methods will do it.

Comment: do i need to create multiple instances of connection for synchronized collection ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask. But yeah, if you want to use more than one connection for all threads, you need to create more than one connection (still for a single pool). Usually, you start with a hardcoded minimum, something like 3. And always check not to exceed the maximum, anywhere from 5-15.

Comment: also refer to the concept JNDI connection : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html and also : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/overview/

Comment: @jsn yes i was asking the same.But i am still not sure how to make it work.

Comment: @Tagneha, you make a class. You put a static synchronized collection in that class. Then you make an instance deposit method which deposits a connection into the pool, and then an instance get method which gets  a connection from the pool. Both methods need to be synchronized. The get method should check the size of the pool, if it is empty, make a new connection and immediately return it. If pool is not empty, remove it from the pool (or mark it as used) and return (make sure you check your max connection limit).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear; I also don't know why you think the way connection pooling works would be different in a desktop application as opposed to server application like Tomcat (ignoring obvious differences like configuration). Both are basically, single process, but multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/), [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) or [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) to give you a few to look at. Each have  their own advantages and disadvantages so it's up to you to choose which is best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at JNDI connection
refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/getStarted/overview/)  and  [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html)link

the basic concept of JNDI is to deal with connection pooling

where you create a pool of database connections and reuse the already existing connections

Comment: Please reformat your answer so it isn't formatted as code, and add the links.